# Number type List Column returns double values instead of integer

Tags: list, column

I've created custom list via browser, and set one of it's column's type to Number. I've set number of decimals to 0, so I was expecting, that numbers this column will store would be of type integer. However when I retrieve values from list programmatically, all the values in this column are doubles, so if I inserted 1, now the returning value is 1.0.

How can I configure my list, so this column will store numbers as integers ?

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column is a double value, it just won't store any precision. Convert to int to use as an int: c# [ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx)